# How to add multiple json values in a single cell of dataTable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

How to add multiple json values in a single cell of dataTable.
I am going through the datatables documentation but cant get a clear example.

I have the following JSON string which I am accessing it through a session into a dataTable.

```
<textarea id="Report" type="text" style="" name="Report">
    [
    {
    "Identifier": "0",
    "LastName": "Cooper",
    "FirstName": "Benny",
    "MiddleInitial": "P",
    "MRN": "7854753",
    "Age": "30",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Location":
        {
            "Bed": "1",
            "Room": "A",
            "unit": "NU1",
            "facility": "Fac1"
        },
    "ServiceDate":"05/03/2013",
    "ChargeAndDx":"99222 - 410.01,428",
    "BillingProvider":"Palmer, James",
    "title":"Add",
    "start":"2013-08-07",
    "url":"#",
    "textColor":"red"
    }] </textarea>
```

on the other page where I am accessing the session in the datatable is aas follows:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

var ReportData=JSON.parse(document.getElementById("Report").innerHTML);
        Report=$('#patientDataTables').dataTable
        ({
            "bJQueryUI":true,
            "bScrollCollapse":true,
            aaData:patientReportData,
            "aoColumns":
                [   {"mData":"LastName","sClass":"left"},
                    {"mData":"ServiceDate","sClass":"left"},
                    {"mData":"ChargeAndDx","sClass":"left"},
                    {"mData":"BillingProvider","sClass":"left"},
                    {"mData":"null","sClass":"center","sDefaultContent":"<a href='' class='editor_menu'>menu</a>"}

                ]
        });
```

In my datatable where the LastName appears I want the FirtName, Middle Initial, MRN and age as well.

How is that done. If some one knows a quick way to do this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Prior to DataTables 1.10.x, you could use the [mRender](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#mrender) parameter like this:

```
"aoColumns":[   
   {"mData":"LastName",
    "sClass":"left", 
    "mRender":function(data, type, full){
       return full.FirstName + full.LastName + full.MiddleInitial;
    }
   },
   {"mData":"ServiceDate","sClass":"left"},
   {"mData":"ChargeAndDx","sClass":"left"},
   {"mData":"BillingProvider","sClass":"left"},
   {"mData":"null","sClass":"center","sDefaultContent":"<a href='' class='editor_menu'>menu</a>"}
]
```

Starting from DataTables 1.10.x, you could use the [columns.render](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) property like this:

```
"columns":[   
   {"data":"LastName",
    "className":"left",
    "render":function(data, type, full, meta){
       return full.FirstName + full.LastName + full.MiddleInitial;
    }
   },
   {"data":"ServiceDate","sClass":"left"},
   {"data":"ChargeAndDx","sClass":"left"},
   {"data":"BillingProvider","className":"left"},
   {"data":"null","className":"center","defaultContent":"<a href='' class='editor_menu'>menu</a>"}
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Till the time I waited for a response I tired an alternative and Cloned the JSON string. Got the FirstName and LastName and Middle initial in a single object/field and then passed it to the dataTable. But I will try this. This looks like and easy alternative.

Comment: Works but You should use "data" parameter, setted with the current row of the JSON array that you have, because in case you have more rows full will contain all objects, not only the current row. Thanks

Comment: Great answer! In addition: If you need those fields to be searchable you can add them in other columns with the parameter 'visible' to 'false' and 'searchable' to 'true'. This way you will see all data in a column but it will still being searchable.