# JSON response to Datatables?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I have the following example to get XML response from Ajax call and appending to table.

```
$("#ajaxform5").submit(function(e) {
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    var request = $.ajax({
        url : formURL,
        type: "GET",
        contentType : "application/xml",
        headers: {
            "Type" : "events"
        },
        success: function(xml){
            $(xml).find('event').each(function(){
                var $event = $(this);
                var id = $event.find("id").text();
                var level = $event.find("level").text();
                var name = $event.find("name").text();
                var attributes01 = $event.find("attributes").children("entry").eq(0).children("string").eq(0).text();
                var attributes02 = $event.find("attributes").children("entry").eq(0).children("string").eq(1).text();
                var attributes11 = $event.find("attributes").children("entry").eq(1).children("string").eq(0).text();
                var attributes12 = $event.find("attributes").children("entry").eq(1).children("string").eq(1).text();
                var attributes21 = $event.find("attributes").children("entry").eq(2).children("string").eq(0).text();
                var attributes22 = $event.find("attributes").children("entry").eq(2).children("string").eq(1).text();
                var attributes31 = $event.find("attributes").children("entry").eq(3).children("string").eq(0).text();
                var attributes32 = $event.find("attributes").children("entry").eq(3).children("string").eq(1).text();
                var attributes41 = $event.find("attributes").children("entry").eq(4).children("string").eq(0).text();
                var attributes42 = $event.find("attributes").children("entry").eq(4).children("string").eq(1).text();
                var userId = $event.find("userId").text();
                var ipaddress = $event.find("ipaddress").text();
                var outcome = $event.find("outcome").text();
                var html = '<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + level + '</td><td>' + name + '</td><td>' +
                    '<div><span class="title">' + attributes01 + '</span> <span>' + attributes02 + '</span></div>' +
                    '<div><span class="title">' + attributes11 + '</span> <span>' + attributes12 + '</span></div>' +
                    '<div><span class="title">' + attributes21 + '</span> <span>' + attributes22 + '</span></div>' +
                    '<div><span class="title">' + attributes31 + '</span> <span>' + attributes32 + '</span></div>' +
                    '<div><span class="title">' + attributes41 + '</span> <span>' + attributes42 + '</span></div>' +
                    '</td><td>' + userId + '</td><td>' + ipaddress + '</td><td>' + outcome + '</td></tr>';
                $('#eventTable').append(html);
            });
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

Now I want to use [Datatables](https://datatables.net/). So I convert response XML to JSON with xml2json(abdmob/x2js) and I got the JSON response below.

JSON response;

```
{
    "list" : {
        "event" : [{
                "dateTime" : "1473858435162",
                "nanoTime" : "438326047248251",
                "id" : "15680",
                "eventTime" : {
                    "time" : "1473851193487",
                    "timezone" : "Asia/Istanbul"
                },
                "level" : "INFORMATION",
                "name" : "Get message content",
                "attributes" : {
                    "entry" : [{
                            "string" : ["metaDataIds", "6"]
                        }, {
                            "string" : ["messageId", "2765"]
                        }, {
                            "string" : ["channel", "Channel[id=44ab0667-d42c-496c-bca2-2bd7eecd6dc9,name=API jQuery Direct]"]
                        }
                    ],
                    "_class" : "linked-hash-map"
                },
                "outcome" : "SUCCESS",
                "userId" : "1",
                "ipAddress" : "127.0.0.1",
                "serverId" : "f85e48e2-32b3-429f-bee5-31630d8143a2"
            }, {
                "dateTime" : "1473858435167",
                "nanoTime" : "438326052034149",
                "id" : "15679",
                "eventTime" : {
                    "time" : "1473851191973",
                    "timezone" : "Asia/Istanbul"
                },
                "level" : "INFORMATION",
                "name" : "Get messages by page limit",
                "attributes" : {
                    "entry" : [{
                            "string" : ["filter", "MessageFilter[maxMessageId=2765,minMessageId=<null>,originalIdUpper=<null>,originalIdLower=<null>,importIdUpper=<null>,importIdLower=<null>,startDate=<null>,endDate=<null>,textSearch=<null>,textSearchRegex=<null>,statuses=<null>,includedMetaDataIds=[6],excludedMetaDataIds=<null>,serverId=<null>,contentSearch=[],metaDataSearch=<null>,textSearchMetaDataColumns=<null>,sendAttemptsLower=<null>,sendAttemptsUpper=<null>,attachment=false,error=false]"]
                        }, {
                            "string" : ["includeContent", "false"]
                        }, {
                            "string" : ["offset", "0"]
                        }, {
                            "string" : ["limit", "21"]
                        }, {
                            "string" : ["channel", "Channel[id=44ab0667-d42c-496c-bca2-2bd7eecd6dc9,name=API jQuery Direct]"]
                        }
                    ],
                    "_class" : "linked-hash-map"
                },
                "outcome" : "SUCCESS",
                "userId" : "1",
                "ipAddress" : "127.0.0.1",
                "serverId" : "f85e48e2-32b3-429f-bee5-31630d8143a2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So my first question, is this JSON response valid for DataTables?
If it is valid, how can I address objects and arrays to row / columns like in my first example?

I tried to insert JSON response to Datatables but I couldn't. You can see the result in the picture.
[response added to rows char by char](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGerQ.png)

I gave the code below for illustration only, you do not want to know how much I drooled to insert data.
I also tried columns.data option to read arrays but failed again.

```
$("#ajaxform6").submit(function(e) {
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    var request = $.ajax({
        url : formURL,
        type: "GET",
        contentType : "application/xml",
        headers: {
            "Type" : "events"
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var x2js = new X2JS();
            var bXML = jqXHR.responseText;
            var jsonObj = x2js.xml_str2json(bXML);
            var json = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
            console.log(json);
            $('#table_id').DataTable( {
                data: json,
                bSort: false,
            } );
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json data is received as response is valid and can be parsed to `datatable`.

You can refer following DataTable code which I have created using your `json` data :

```js
var jsdata = {
  "list" : {
   "event" : [
     {
      "dateTime" : "1473858435162",
      "nanoTime" : "438326047248251",
      "id" : "15680",
      "eventTime" : {
       "time" : "1473851193487",
       "timezone" : "Asia/Istanbul"
      },
      "level" : "INFORMATION",
      "name" : "Get message content",
      "attributes" : {
       "entry" : [
         {
          "string" : [ "metaDataIds", "6" ]
         },
         {
          "string" : [ "messageId", "2765" ]
         },
         {
          "string" : [ "channel",
            "Channel[id=44ab0667-d42c-496c-bca2-2bd7eecd6dc9,name=API jQuery Direct]" ]
         } ],
       "_class" : "linked-hash-map"
      },
      "outcome" : "SUCCESS",
      "userId" : "1",
      "ipAddress" : "127.0.0.1",
      "serverId" : "f85e48e2-32b3-429f-bee5-31630d8143a2"
     },
     {
      "dateTime" : "1473858435167",
      "nanoTime" : "438326052034149",
      "id" : "15679",
      "eventTime" : {
       "time" : "1473851191973",
       "timezone" : "Asia/Istanbul"
      },
      "level" : "INFORMATION",
      "name" : "Get messages by page limit",
      "attributes" : {
       "entry" : [
         {
          "string" : [
            "filter",
            "MessageFilter[maxMessageId=2765,minMessageId=<null>,originalIdUpper=<null>,originalIdLower=<null>,importIdUpper=<null>,importIdLower=<null>,startDate=<null>,endDate=<null>,textSearch=<null>,textSearchRegex=<null>,statuses=<null>,includedMetaDataIds=[6],excludedMetaDataIds=<null>,serverId=<null>,contentSearch=[],metaDataSearch=<null>,textSearchMetaDataColumns=<null>,sendAttemptsLower=<null>,sendAttemptsUpper=<null>,attachment=false,error=false]" ]
         },
         {
          "string" : [ "includeContent", "false" ]
         },
         {
          "string" : [ "offset", "0" ]
         },
         {
          "string" : [ "limit", "21" ]
         },
         {
          "string" : [ "channel",
            "Channel[id=44ab0667-d42c-496c-bca2-2bd7eecd6dc9,name=API jQuery Direct]" ]
         } ],
       "_class" : "linked-hash-map"
      },
      "outcome" : "SUCCESS",
      "userId" : "1",
      "ipAddress" : "127.0.0.1",
      "serverId" : "f85e48e2-32b3-429f-bee5-31630d8143a2"
     } ]
  }
 };

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table_id').DataTable({
   data : jsdata.list.event,
   columns : [ {
    title : "Id",
    data : 'id'
   }, {
    title : "Level",
    data : 'level'
   }, {
    title : "Name",
    data : 'name'
   }, {
    title : "UserId",
    data : 'userId'
   }, {
    title : "Ip Address",
    data : 'ipAddress'
   }

   ]
  });
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="table_id" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @abhijeet.
One more thing, how can I add two data in one field? For example, I want show ID and Level in one field.

Comment: I updated my comment but you didn't get notification for this @Abhijeet.
Do you have any idea how can I add two data in one field? For example, I want show "ID" and "Level" in one field.

Comment: @ObsessiO you can follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081967/how-to-add-multiple-json-values-in-a-single-cell-of-datatable

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to use `JSON.stringify`
- You need to specify data property for each column with `columns.data` property

Sample code for 2-column table is shown below. Add more `column.data` entries for additional columns.

```
$('#table_id').DataTable( {
   data: jsonObj.list.event,
   columns: [
      { data: 'name' },
      { data: 'level' }
   ]
});
```