# How can I concatenate data from two database columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have two columns in my table first name and last name . How do I concatenate them ? I have seen this asked before  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081967/how-to-add-multiple-json-values-in-a-single-cell-of-datatable) but cant get any of the answers to work.

```
 var table = $("#LockerTable").DataTable({
                    ajax: {
                        url: "/api/lockers",
                        dataSrc: "",
                        "data": null
                           },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            data: "lockerNumber"
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "location"
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "student.firstName",
                            "defaultContent": "Not assigned yet"
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

**Update:**
based on annoyingmouse's answer I tried 
as follows:

```
 $('#example').DataTable({
                "ajax": {                       
                    "url": '/api/lockers',
                    "data": null,
                    "dataSrc": ""                                            
                },

                "columns": [
                  {
                      "data": "lockerNumber"
                  },
                  {
                      "data": "location"
                  },
                  {
                      "data": "student",
                      "defaultContent": "Not Assigned Yet",
                      "render": function (d, t, r) {
                          return r.student.firstName;
                      }
                  }
                ]
            });
```

the result is

> Cannot read property 'firstName' of null

**Here is how data is returned When navigating to api/lockers**

```
<LockerVm>
<LockerId>1</LockerId>
<LockerNumber>1</LockerNumber>
<StudentId>1</StudentId>
<student>
<FirstName>David</FirstName>
<LastName>Goldberg</LastName>
<StudentId>1</StudentId>
</student>
</LockerVm>
```

**update 2:**

When I log in the console I get the data but I strangely I get the same data  4 times (partial view below). *Note: Not all lockers are assigned to students*.

[image]

Comment: Are you passing XML into the DataTable? It doesn't know how to deal with that... and, from looking at your data it's a singleton...? Or are you sending more data?

Comment: I didn't have an issue with the other data.  Yes there is more data, I am just showing a bit of  sample data.I am able to get everything but cant concatenate the two

Comment: If that's the structure of your data then I'd guess the issue is with a row not having that set. Try to `console.log(r)` in your render function. One thing that does jump out is that your data has `FirstName` rather than `firstName` (and `LastName` rather than `lastName`), that's not it is it?

Comment: no I have added code  in config file  
            settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

Comment: So your result includes two arrays of objects? Because I see no student records there...? If so you'll need to mash them together in your ajax result before passing them to DataTable proper.

Comment: Updated my answer and JSFiddle

Comment: A for effort. I am not sure what echo/json is but your code does not work for me. I see it working in js fiddle but it is not working for me. I get "Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null at render.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166710/discussion-between-annoyingmouse-and-curious-programmer).

Answer (score 0):

You need a render function here:

```
var data = [{
    "student": {
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "Smith"
    },
    "lockernumber": "1",
    "location": "Wales"
  },
  {
    "student": {
      "firstname": "Jane",
      "lastname": "Smith"
    },
    "lockernumber": "2",
    "location": "Scotland"
  },
  {
    "student": {
      "firstname": "Joe",
      "lastname": "Smith"
    },
    "lockernumber": "3",
    "location": "England"
  },
  {
    "lockernumber": "4",
    "location": "Ireland"
  }
];

$('#example').DataTable({
  "ajax": {
    "type": 'POST',
    "dataType": 'json',
    "url": '/echo/json/',
    "data": {
      "json": JSON.stringify(data)
    },
    "dataSrc": ""
  },
  columns: [{
      "data": "lockernumber"
    },
    {
      "data": "location"
    },
    {
      "data": "location",
      "render": function(d, t, r) {
        if (r.hasOwnProperty('student')) {
          var student = r.student;
          var returnString = "";
          if (student.hasOwnProperty('firstname')) {
            returnString = student.firstname;
          }
          if (student.hasOwnProperty('lastname')) {
            if (returnString.length) {
              returnString += " " + student.lastname;
            } else {
              returnString = student.lastname;
            }
          }
          return returnString;
        } else {
          return "Not assigned"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

To an extent, it doesn't matter what `data` you use for the column but you need to access the whole row (`r` in the example) and grab what you need in the `render` function. The code uses ES6 arrow functions and template literals but it should be easy enough to convert to ES5. Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/svoeg1fv/). Please also take note of the `dataSrc`.

Hope that helps.

**Note**

Please be aware that I'm using JSFiddles ability to mock AJAX requests, you need to use your own AJAX call which should remain the same as it was.

Comment: Can you give an example of your data?