# Datatables displaying multiple data in columns

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

[image]

I am using datatables for displaying data from mysql to frontend but i am stuck in displaying multiple designations in designation columns

code for initializing datatables

```
script(type='text/javascript').
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#mytab').DataTable({
       dom: 'Bfrtip',
       buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf','print'
        ],

  });
      });
```

for retreiving data from database

```
 tbody
        if user
        each user, i in users
          tr.profiledata
            th= user.getDataValue('name') 
            th= user.getDataValue('stack_holder')
            th= user.getDataValue('client_name')
            th.reference #{user.getDataValue('reference')}
            th= user.getDataValue('document_type')
            th= user.getDataValue('service_type')
            th= user.getDataValue('year')
            th
              if((a = user.getDataValue('PO_start_date'))!=null)
                  |  #{a.getDate() + '-' + (a.getMonth()+1) + '-' + a.getFullYear()}
            th
              if((a = user.getDataValue('PO_end_date'))!=null)
                |  #{a.getDate() + '-' + (a.getMonth()+1) + '-' + a.getFullYear()}
            th
              if((a = user.getDataValue('reminder_date'))!=null)
                |  #{a.getDate() + '-' + (a.getMonth()+1) + '-' + a.getFullYear()} 

            if(user.getDataValue('transaction_tbls').length > 0)
              for tr in user.getDataValue('transaction_tbls')
                th= (tr['dataValues'])['designation']
                th= (tr['dataValues'])['quantity']
                th= (tr['dataValues'])['rate']
            else
              th
              th
              th
            th= user.getDataValue('signature_status')
            th= (a = user.getDataValue('createdAt')).getDate() + '-' + (a.getMonth()+1) + '-' + a.getFullYear()
            th= user.getDataValue('client') 
            th= user.getDataValue('contact') 
            th= user.getDataValue('contactperson') 
            th= user.getDataValue('contactnumber') 
            th= user.getDataValue('emailid') 
            th= user.getDataValue('period_of_contract')
            th= user.getDataValue(' payment_term')
            th= user.getDataValue('financial_year')
```

I get object of my table like transaction_tbl:[] in response from server

Comment: Please share your code with us as an [mcve] and not just an image of the result.

Comment: Don't add your code as a comment, [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51966936/edit) your question

Comment: @PANKAJ DALVI, can you add [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) link, where we can run code and identify where is error?.

Comment: do you want data to display like 'tester, developer, BDE' under same cell right?

Comment: Why don't you use AJAX option of DataTables? That way DataTables will manage the table itself. You will only need to return an array or object from the server.[More on AJAX option](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax)

Comment: @yash yes exactly i want tester developer bde to come one below other

Comment: @PANKAJDALVI can you add some more code in your question, full javascript and html code? and also add json response that you get.

Comment: code is in node js and its pretty big and i have used jade and not html

Comment: @yash i have updated

Comment: sorry  @PANKAJDALVI, I'm not comfortable with node js, but please check your response json has same structure like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081967/how-to-add-multiple-json-values-in-a-single-cell-of-datatable)

Comment: this is still unsolved